# What range of ports do remote kernels use?

Tags: remote-access

I'm trying to [run a remote kernel](http://support.wolfram.com/kb/12495), but my local system administrator is wary of opening up ports for incoming connections.

**Is there are particular range of ports that *Mathematica* uses for remote kernels?**

Even if it's a wide range (e.g. 40000-70000), such an answer would still be helpful to me.

Comment: Most likely it's the entire [ephemeral range](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ephemeral_port). This is usually controllable by the OS, although you should be aware that reducing it to a much narrower range may cause problems if you need to open a lot of network connections simultaneously.

Comment: Related: [65953](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/65953/remote-kernel-through-ssh).