# Running remote kernel - free frontend license?

Tags: windows, remote-access

I was wondering, is there any way to remotely connect to a *Mathematica* kernel with some free front end software?

I have one (home-use) license, so I have *Mathematica* installed on my main computer. However, I may want to perform *Mathematica* computations on a secondary laptop - I don't have a second license though. Is it then possible to install a *Mathematica* front end (or some equivalent that doesn't require another license) and then remotely access the kernel from the licensed computer?

I'm not using Linux, so SSHing isn't very viable... unless it's actually possible?

Comment: I doubt it, why not just remote desktop into home machine? Available on all platforms I'm aware of, and with any reasonable network speed performance will be fine except perhaps on rendering torturous graphics.

Comment: Thanks for replying! Yeah, I'm currently just using Streamtop to remote to my desktop, but there's some graphics overhead and lag that I wanted to see if there was an alternative. But it looks like there's not...

Comment: Take a look at nomachine  (really fast for x11 environments, but also works on Windows) and Anydesk. I use both, fine for me even with pretty hairy graphics outputs...

Answer (score 3):

You could use Raspberry Pi as your free Mathematica frontend which uses your Mac/Linux as backend/server. (I haven't tried it on Windows)

There is a limitation, the version numbers of Mathematica for Mac/Linux and Mathematica for Raspberry Pi should be same, otherwise you can't use remote kernels from your Raspberry Pi.

If you want to know how to configure remote kernel, please refer to [remote kernel through SSH](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/65953/remote-kernel-through-ssh/105573#105573)

You can configure remote kernels with the script. If your remote Wolfram kernels are up and running, then you can use the command below to test if it works.

[image]