# Connect to remote kernels with ssh in MMA 11.2.0

Tags: remote-access

I used these code in this post [remote kernel through SSH](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/65953/remote-kernel-through-ssh)

```
Needs["SubKernels`RemoteKernels`"]
Parallel`Settings`$MathLinkTimeout = 100
user = "user";
ssh = "export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=;ssh";(*ssh program name.If you install \
GOW on Windows,then this should work,otherwise put the path \
yourself*)
math = 
 "MathKernel" <> 
  " -wstp -linkmode Connect `4` -linkname `2` -subkernel -noinit >&  \
/dev/null &";
number = 2;(*number of parallel kernels to launch*)

machine = "ipv6 addr";
remote = SubKernels`RemoteKernels`RemoteMachine[machine, 
  ssh <> " " <> user <> "@" <> machine <> " " <>
   " \"" <> math <> "\"", number]

Print[remote // InputForm]
kerns = LaunchKernels[remote]

ParallelEvaluate[$MachineName]
```

but I can't get those kernels started, and I got a `General::time: Operation LaunchKernels timed out after 10. seconds.` error. BTW I used rsa keys so no password is required.

My MMA version is 11.2.0, and I'm connecting lower version (11.0.0). I tested connection between two 11.0.0 with the same code and everything worked out fine.

I used ipv6 but I don't think that's the issue here, since in 11.0.0 everything worked out fine.

I also tried connecting two 11.2.0 machine and got

```
LinkConnect::linkc: 
   -- Message text not found -- (
    LinkObject[39853@10.8.0.6,45079@10.8.0.6, 3, 1])
LinkConnect::linkc: 
   -- Message text not found -- (
    LinkObject[43695@10.8.0.6,34773@10.8.0.6, 3, 1])

LinkConnect::linkc: 
   -- Message text not found -- (
    LinkObject[46231@10.8.0.6,37321@10.8.0.6, 3, 1])

LinkConnect::linkc: 
   -- Message text not found -- (
    LinkObject[42987@10.8.0.6,39781@10.8.0.6, 3, 1])

LinkConnect::linkc: 
   -- Message text not found -- (
    LinkObject[44499@10.8.0.6,43279@10.8.0.6, 3, 1])

LinkConnect::linkc: 
   -- Message text not found -- (
    LinkObject[37985@10.8.0.6,37443@10.8.0.6, 3, 1])
```