# Remote Kernel over ssh - Timeout

Tags: remote-access

For a long time I've been using remote Kernels in Mathematica 10 & 11. But since some time ago I cannot connect to my remote machines on 11.3 anymore. I always get the error message

```
General::time: Operation LaunchKernels timed out after 10.` seconds.
```

I've tried different launch commands, e.g.

```
ssh -x -f `1` math -wstp -linkmode Connect `4` -linkname `2` -subkernel -noinit
ssh -x -f `1` math -mathlink -linkmode Connect `4` -linkname `2` -subkernel -noinit
```

I also switched `math` for `wolfram` and `MathKernel`. I tried the answer from this [post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/65953/remote-kernel-through-ssh), but same result. It seems that the option `` Parallel`Settings`$MathLinkTimeout = 100 `` does not work for me, I always get a timeout at 10s. On my remote machine I see the ssh connection in the log files, so ssh should not be the problem.

I didn't have this problem with previous versions, remote kernels always worked without problem. Was there some change introduced in version 11.2 or 11.3 that changed the behaviour of remote kernels? Can I set the timeout somehow (`$MathLinkTimeout` doesn't work)?

Thanks

Comment: I'd consider this a bug and I'd report it to support@wolfram.com.

Comment: Hm ok, I thought this shouldn't be normal behaviour, I just wanted to check if someone has had the same problem and maybe found a solution.

Comment: This won’t work in v11.3 anymore, they made lots of breaking changes in how links are set up

Comment: Is there any other way to connect to remote kernels now? I haven't found anything in the official documentation. There they only talk about the ssh connection the way I always set it up in older versions...