# Launch Kernels on Windows 10 from Raspberry Pi (linux) over SSH

Tags: parallelization, windows, linux, remote-access, kernel-startup

I am trying to launch remote kernels on a Windows 10 PC (remote) from a Raspberry Pi 4 (Master or local).  Both machines have V12 installed.

On the Windows machine, I have installed OpenSSH per [these](https://www.tutorialdocs.com/article/windows-openssh-tutorial.html) instructions and can SSH into the Windows machine using passwordless (key) SSH.

From the Raspberry Pi terminal:

```
ssh username@IP_Address
```

opens a Administrator C:\Windows\system32\cmd CMD in the Raspberry Pi terminal with the prompt:

```
user@WindowsMachineName C:\Users\USER>
```

So I know passwordless SSH works.  This is generally a prerequisite for launching remote kernels.

I then use code from this [example](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/65953/remote-kernel-through-ssh/105573#105573).  This code has worked for me launching remote kernels from a Raspberry Pi (local) to another Raspberry Pi (remote) as well as from a Raspberry Pi (local) to a Mac (remote).  I am running into trouble launching remote kernels on the Windows 10 machine.

```
Needs["SubKernels`RemoteKernels`"]
Parallel`Settings`$MathLinkTimeout = 100
user = "myuser";
password = "mypassword";
ssh =  "export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=;ssh"; 
math = "C:\\Program Files\\Wolfram Research\\Wolfram \
Desktop\\12.0\\MathKernel" <> 
       " -wstp -linkmode Connect `4` -linkname `2` -subkernel -noinit >&  \
/dev/null &";
number = 4; (*number of parallel kernels to launch*)
machine = "WindowsMachineIP";
remote = SubKernels`RemoteKernels`RemoteMachine[machine, 
  ssh <> " " <> user <> "@" <> machine <> " " <> "-pw " <> password <>
    " \"" <> math <> "\"", number]

kerns = LaunchKernels[remote]
```

gives error

```
LaunchRemote::rsh: Command export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=;ssh USER@WindowsMachineIP "C:\Program Files\Wolfram Research\Wolfram Desktop\12.0\MathKernel -wstp -linkmode Connect -linkprotocol TCPIP -linkname 38417@192.168.1.9,39313@192.168.1.9 -subkernel -noinit >&  /dev/null &" may have failed (exit code 256).
```

Should I even be trying to launch Kernels over SSH or is there a better method to start remote kernels on a Windows machine (remote) from Linux (local, raspberry pi)?